# In Ruby, how can I remove numeric words from a phrase without splitting phrase into words and losing word delimiters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to remove numeric words from a phrase. I am writing the following:

```
phrase = 'hello 234234 word'
words = phrase.split(/\W/)
words.reject!{ |w| w.match(/^\d+$/) }
words.join(' ')
```

or, one-liner:

```
phrase = phrase.split(/\W/).reject{ |w| w.match(/^\d+$/) }.join(' ')
```

Example:

```
"hello 123 word" should end "hello word"
"hello 123word" should end "hello 123word"
"hello 123.word" should end "hello word"
```

The problem with this solution is that it removes the word delimiters too. (See the 3rd example above)

Is there a better, neater way to do that and save word delimiters at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex does the job:

```
phrase.gsub!(/\b\d+\b/, "")
```

This `gsub` gets rid of the numeric words.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
phrase.gsub!(/ \d+ /, " ")
```

The brackets are required to prevent ruby thinking that you're trying a line-continuation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. However, your solution is wrong. I need a way to remove **numeric words** (I do not know whether this is the correct english, though). In other words, I want to remove **numbers** from phrase. If the phrase is _hello 123world_ this needs to be returned as _hello 123world_ because **123world** is not a numeric word, is not strictly speaking a number.

Comment: Ok, solution amended to work for that. It should work for you now.

Comment: I have ammended the question to clarify that the solution should recognize word delimiters different to blanks (your solution takes care only for blanks) and if possibly to retain the word delimiters in the output.